# Operations between columns between multi index dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to perform an operation between the columns of Index1, identified by 'A' and 'B', based on all the subcolumns (Index2). I have multiple dates, i.e. multiple rows.

What I have:

```
d = {'Date':'20191101', 'Index1': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'Index2': ['a','b','c','a','b','c'], 'Value':[0,2,0,3,5,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['Index1','Index2'], values='Value', aggfunc=np.sum)

Index1    A         B      
Index2    a  b  c   a  b  c
Date                      
20191101  0  2  0   3  5  4
```

What I would like:

```
Index1    A         B         A-B
Index2    a  b  c   a  b  c   a  b  c
Date                                
20191101  0  2  0   3  5  4   -3 -3 -4
```

Would you have an idea on how I can perform this ?

Many thanks and kind regards!

Edit:
I would now like to perform several operations, for example A-B+C. The input is A-B+C, I can have 1 or 2 or more operations so I need a recursive algorithm.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a recursive function.
data contains the raw series A, B and C.
The functions will process ['A-B'], add it to data and call back Combine_Indexes(['A-B','C'], ['+'], data).
Recursivity stops when ops is empty.

```
data = Combine_Indexes(['A','B','C'], ['-','+'], data)
```

The function:

```
def Combine_Indexes(indexes, ops, df):
    if len(ops)>0: #there are still operations to do
        op = ops[0]
        index1 = indexes[0]
        index2 = indexes[1]
        if op == '-':
            data_combined = pd.DataFrame([df[(index1,x)] - df[(index2,x)] for x in df.columns.levels[1]]).T
        elif op == '+':
            data_combined = pd.DataFrame([df[(index1,x)] + df[(index2,x)] for x in df.columns.levels[1]]).T   
        data_combined.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[index1 + op + index2]*len(df.columns.levels[1]),  df.columns.levels[1]])
        data_combined = df.merge(data_combined, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        indexes = [index1 + op + index2] + indexes[2:]
        return Combine_Indexes(indexes, ops[1:], data_combined) #we call back the function with the new indexes list, ops list and df
    else: #no more operation
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. Is it your desire output?

```
a_b = pd.DataFrame([df[('A',x)] - df[('B',x)] for x in df.columns.levels[1]]).T
a_b.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A-B']*len(df.columns.levels[1]),  df.columns.levels[1]])

a_b

Out[1]:
            A-B 
    Index2  a   b   c
Date            
20191101    -3  -3  -4


df.merge(a_b, left_index = True, right_index = True) 

Out[2]:

    Index1  A           B           A-B
    Index2  a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
    Date                                    
20191101    0   2   0   3   5   4   -3  -3  -4
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!